# Is there any way to have a background image in MigraDoc / PDFsharp?

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

I want to create a cover page that has text over a background image.  Is this possible in MigraDoc / PDFsharp?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

Background image can be a page from a PDF file or a "real" image (JPEG, BMP, ...).

Add the background image first at an absolute position. Following text will be rendered above the image.

See members Left, Top, RelativeVertical, RelativeHorizontal, etc.
See also here (Images and TextFrames are both Shapes):
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=3133#p3133

Comment: is there anyway to have an image go outside the borders to the end of a page ??  I have tried all of the options on that link but still showing up inside the border

Comment: Yes, with RelativeXxx.Page you can draw that image at an absolute position with an absolute size. I used this to fill the complete page with an image coming from a different PDF file.
There is no clipping at the border, so with the correct settings of position and size you can fill the whole page.